# how would I enter this function into toad to run?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Here is the code

```
vResult VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  fvData:=TRIM(fvData);
  IF SUBSTR(fvData,LENGTH(fvData)-1,1)<>'*' THEN
    fvData:=fvData||'**';
  END IF;
  vResult:=SUBSTR(fvData,1,InStr(fvData,'^^') - 1);
  fvData:=SUBSTR(fvData,InStr(fvData,'^^') + 3);
  RETURN vResult;
END StringExtract;
/
```

I have tried entering different ways, with `fvdata=365` but nothing happens, I have try entering small SQL like

```
select InStr(367,'^^^^') - 1 
  from dual;
```

but I can't figure out how to do this big function.

Comment: Is this a snippet or a full text of the *function*?

Comment: full text of the function

Comment: No, it isn't. It contains no definition of what `fvData` is, and no definition of the function name or parameter types.

Comment: 1) You are missing `DECLARE` keyword at the very beginning to be that code of yours an anonymous PL/SQL block, which is treated as a procedure and does not allow to return an expression using `return` statement.2) You are missing [create or replace function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5011.htm#i2153260) `<<name of function>> return <<data type(varchar2)>> is` statement for your function to be a function (stored procedure/schema object), which you can reference in the select statement. Also the variable `fvData` is not being declared anywhere.

Comment: also what's the point in the final line before the RETURN statement? `fvData:=SUBSTR(fvData,InStr(fvData,'^^') + 3);` - the result of this will never get used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt to help you get this working take a look at the following code. I have left out the detail of your function so we don't complicate things but you should be able to just plug that back in.

```
DECLARE

    inputValue VARCHAR2(200) := :inputValue; -- << this bind variable allows you to provide different input each you run the code

    FUNCTION stringExtract(fvData varchar2) RETURN varchar2
    IS
       vResult VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN

        vResult := TRIM(fvData);

        RETURN vResult;

    END stringExtract;

BEGIN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LENGTH(inputValue));

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LENGTH(stringExtract(inputValue)));

END;
```

Hopefully you can take that as a template and adapt to get your program running.